ProOptimizer in MaxScript
I currently need to apply the ProOptimizer modifier to the Objects in my scene based on the geometry name, so that I can get different reductions based on differnt types of objects. However I didn't find any way to add this specific modifier using MaxScript
I have tried using the "add modifier" function, but wasn't able to specify the parameters as the Vertex % didn't show up as a valid one in the script editor. I tried using ChatGPT to see if it was of any help, and it did generate a useful script, but it only made a template of the ProOptimizer, it didn't apply to the objects in the scene.
